# Ubuntu GNOME - Evolution E-Mail client not working with outlook as Two-Step verification

Tags: gnome, evolution

So today, I´ve switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. And I love it.

But GNOME came with its own email client, called Evolution.

Now I try to attempt to login with my email account, thats from outlook.com, but it refuses to login. And I have a feeling its due the two step verification I have on my phone.

How can I fix this?

Kind regards,
OctaVive.

Comment: Are you setting up evolution on your phone ? if not look at __application password generation for outlook__ this sets up a password for each of your app from your outlook account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all mail applications do well with **two step authentication** so microsoft setup **application password generation** to help with this.

Steps:

1. Open your outlook account
2. click on your **account image** and select **view account**

   - [image]
3. select **security & privacy** from the top menu
4. select **more security settings** from under **account security**
5. scroll down and select **create a new app password** under **app password**
6. copy the new app password generated and use that in evolution

Comment: Selected as best answer.